# Python seaborn heatmap grid - Not taking expected columns

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I have following pandas dataframe. Basically, 7 different action categories, 5 different targets, each category has 1 or many unique endpoints, then each endpoint got a certain score in each target. 
There are total 250 endpoints.

```
action,target,endpoint,score
Category1,target1,endpoint1,813.0
Category1,target2,endpoint1,757.0
Category1,target3,endpoint1,155.0
Category1,target4,endpoint1,126.0
Category1,target5,endpoint1,75.5
Category2,target1,endpoint2,106.0
Category2,target1,endpoint3,101.0
Category2,target1,endpoint4,499.0
Category2,target1,endpoint5,207.0
Category2,target2,endpoint2,316.0
Category2,target2,endpoint3,208.0
Category2,target2,endpoint4,161.0
Category2,target2,endpoint5,198.0
<omit>
Category3,target1,endpoint8,193.0
Category3,target1,endpoint9,193.0
Category3,target1,endpoint10,193.0
Category3,target1,endpoint11,193.0
Category3,target2,endpoint8,193.0
Category3,target2,endpoint9,193.0
<List goes on...>
```

Now, I wanted to map out this dataframe as heatmap per category.
So, I used seabron facet grid heatmap with the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv('rawData.csv')
data = data.drop('Unnamed: 0', 1)


def facet_heatmap(data, **kwargs):


    data2 = data.pivot(index="target", columns='endpoint', values='score')
    ax1 = sns.heatmap(data2, cmap="YlGnBu", linewidths=2)

    for item in ax1.get_yticklabels():
        item.set_rotation(0)

    for item in ax1.get_xticklabels():
        item.set_rotation(70)


with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):

    g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="action", col_wrap=7, size=5, aspect=0.5)

cbar_ax = g.fig.add_axes([.92, .3, .02, .4])  

g = g.map_dataframe(facet_heatmap, cbar=cbar_ax, min=0, vmax=2000)
# <-- Specify the colorbar axes and limits

g.set_titles(col_template="{col_name}", fontweight='bold', fontsize=18)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(right=3)  # <-- Add space so the colorbar doesn't overlap the plot

plt.savefig('seabornPandas.png', dpi=400)
plt.show()
```

It actually generates heatmap grid. However, the problem is the each heatmap uses the same column for some reason. See attached screenshot below.

[image: As you may notice, it is quite odd.] 
(Please ignore color bar and limits.)

This is quite odd. First, the Index is not in order. Second, each heatmap box only takes the last three endpoints (Endpoint 248, 249, and 250). This is incorrect. For category 1, it should take endpoint 1 only. I don't expect a gray box there..

For category2, it should take endpoint 2,3,4,5. Not endpoint 248, 249, 250.

How can I fix these two issues? Any suggestion or comments are welcome.

Comment: Did you make sure that `data2` looks lthe way you think it looks?

Comment: Sounds like you need to turn off x axis sharing, but in general, if the x factor is nested inside the col factor (rather than crossed), it isn't exactly the right structure to plot with a facet grid.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes, I confirmed data 2 looks as expected. Each endpoints are shown up per target.

Comment: @mwaskom Could you help me understand how to turn off x axis sharing? I just would like to try to see how it is going to help.

Comment: There is a `sharex` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mwaskom suggested: use the sharex parameter to fix your issues:

```
...

with sns.plotting_context(font_scale=5.5):

g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="action", col_wrap=7, size=5, aspect=0.5,
                 sharex=False)

...
```